# Why is generator object returned rather than normal tuple

Tags: python, tuples, generator

I have the following:

```
display_width = 400
centered_width = display_width/2
pt1 = (0,0,0)
adjustedPt1 = (x+1 for x in pt1)
print(adjustedPt1)
```

which returns the generator object:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1064c01d0>
```

If I however, instead use a list:

```
display_width = 400
centered_width = display_width/2
pt1 = (0,0,0)
adjustedPt1 = [x+1 for x in pt1]
print(adjustedPt1)
```

it returns: `[1,1,1]`

Comment: Try `tuple(x+1 for x in pt1)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I am still confused as to why it is formatted as an object by default, unlike the list which isn't.